# Python/Matplotlib colorbar-ticklabel distance

Tags: python, matplotlib

Does anyone know how to change the distance of the colorbar ticklabels with respect to the colorbar in Python/Matplotlib? Thanks!

So for example, here I would like to move the 0, 0.5 and 1.0 to the left or right with respect to the colorbar:

[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean: do you want e.g. more spacing between the tickmarks (that is, have them at different values on the colour bar)? Or do you want the ticklabels to be further away from the colourbar, i.e., to create some extra spacing between the labels and the colourbar? An example (with e.g. and arrow indicating what space you want to change) would be good.

Comment: Hi Evert, I mean the latter case that you mentioned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Borrowing from the [standalone colourbars example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/colorbar_only.html), this shows how to

- change the spacing between the tickmarks (just specify them manually)
- change the distance of the ticklabels to the colourbar. The trick here is to obtain the relevant axis (`cb1.ax`) and apply the right tick parameter (`pad=...`).

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import matplotlib as mpl
fig = pyplot.figure(figsize=(8,3))
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.70, 0.9, 0.15])
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.35, 0.9, 0.15])
cmap = mpl.cm.cool
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=5, vmax=10)
cb1 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax1, cmap=cmap, norm=norm,
                                orientation='horizontal')
cb1.set_label('Negative spacing')
cb1.set_ticks([5.5, 7.5, 9.5])
cb1.ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(pad=-15)
cb2 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax2, cmap=cmap, norm=norm,
                            orientation='horizontal')
cb2.set_label('Far away')
cb2.set_ticks([5.5, 7.5, 9.5])
cb2.ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(pad=30)
pyplot.savefig('colorbar-ticklabels.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Great thanks a lot Evert! cb1.ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(pad=-15) was indeed what I was looking for :).